# View selected photo inside a ng-repeat in another div

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have a table that has data in ng-repeat. A column contains photos. When I edit a specific data in the table, the photo of the data that I have been selected should be shown. How can I possibly do it?

In my table the code goes like this

```
<td>
    <img ng-src='{{ item.photo }}' height='50px'>
</td>
```

And in my other div it goes like this

```
<img ng-src='pphoto' style="float:right;width:200px;height:100px;" alt="img"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the element via a function on ng-click and bind that to a variable.
Demo

```js
 var app = angular.module("app", []);

 app.controller("listController", ["$scope",
   function($scope) {
     $scope.options = [{
       'title': 'Title1',
       'label': 'Zip code',
       'type': 'xxx',
       'photo': 'https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300'
     },
     {
       'title': 'Title2',
       'label': 'Zip code2',
       'type': 'yyyy',
       'photo': 'https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSSYBkITzCk_4rBfHIkRTwSLf_VJ5OqmPCrLZV7mZZ2s8RzZJgf5RFhzJ0'
     }

    ];

     $scope.pphoto;

     $scope.assign = function(item) {

       $scope.pphoto = item.photo;
     }
   }
 ]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="listController">
    <div>
      <table>
        <td ng-repeat="item in options">
          <img ng-src='{{item.photo}}' height='50px'>
          <button ng-click="assign(item)">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </table>
      <div>Q
        <img ng-src='{{pphoto}}' alt="img" />
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```